# Search Queries Not Showing on Google Webmaster Tools after Customizing URL

Tags: search, blogger, google-search-console

I have linked my blogger site hinditracks.blogspot.com to Google webmaster tools and everything was just working fine. But after when I customized it's url to [www.hinditracks.in](http://www.hinditracks.in) Indexing, Crowling, Sitemap all are still working fine except **Search Queries**. There is not any data showing in Search Queries on Webmaster tools.
If I'm setting webmaster tools again for new url there may be problem of duplicate contents. Also I don't want to remove already indexed pages.

How to show Search Queries on webmaster tools now?

Answer (score 0):

You have to revert it to hinditracks.com, I mean add a site with dot com domain, and it should be working fine. If you are not facing issues on your latest links indexing with Google then I hope changing the domain should solve your problem.